# C# Passing an Optional Function to another Function

Tags: c#, optional-parameters, function-parameter

I know that in C# you can pass a function as a parameter to another function with something that looks like this:

```
public bool DoSomething(int param1, int param2 = 0, Func<bool, bool> f) 
{
//Do Some work
//Run function f
bool i = f(true);
return true;
}
```

I also know that if you initialize one of the parameters, in my example, the second parameter (int param2 = 0), then the parameter is optional.

How can I make the third parameter (**the function f**) as an **optional parameter**?
What should I initialize it to?

I would appreciate some help!

Comment: What you ask for is called a "Delegate". One of the many things they had to invent to replace naked pointers. I am unsure if Delegates can be combiend with optiuonal parameters, however.

Comment: Initialize it to a `Func<bool, bool>`? i.e., `(something) => !something`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public bool DoSomething(int param1, int param2 = 0, Func<bool, bool> f = null) 
{
 ...
}
```